# post method success function doesn't run in javascript 200

Tags: jquery, django, json, post

Hi I post **json** to **django** web service unfortunately success function doesn't fire even I get result **200** for this method I have change datatype to "**json**" "**text**" "**html**" but get nothing

the web service protocol is **jsonrpc**

thank you for your help

```
function displaySearchResult(response) {

        if (response.result)
                alert(response.result);

        else if (response.error)
                alert("Search error: " + response.error.message);
};


var url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/django/json/";

var request = {};
request.method = "liveScore";
request.params = {};
request.params.date = "1392/08/04";
request.params.hash = "123";
request.id = 1;
request.jsonrpc = "2.0";

$.post(url JSON.stringify(request), displaySearchResult, "json");
```

Comment: if you're dataType is json and you're getting 200 but no success, that means your server isn't returning json.

Comment: thank you but I want to handle the response even it is not json

Comment: what is `textStatus` value in `displaySearchResult(data,textStatus,jqXHR)`?

Comment: is textStatus  needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain you're requesting data from is not the same as the originating domain, then the request will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) unless you use CORS or JSONP. You would need to check the API documentation to see if these are supported and how to use them.